# React, npm start issue

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, npm-install

[image: the error i get]

this is the error I get when I try to run npm start
not really sure what it is saying

Comment: Please post your ```start``` script in ```package.json```

Comment: Please to not present text as a pixel raster: copy and paste into your post, as a block quote.

Comment: thank you for the response I fixed it I had problem with globals

Answer (score 0):

Try running npm install command again and if that doesnt work out, Try downgrading react scripts.

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Comment: thanks for the response I had problem with global variables and I fixed it

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue when I create my first react project.But after getting this error I rechecked the way how I run the project.In that time I found I gave 'npm start' by opening terminal in wrong file directory.If you open your terminal and you are already in root folder, then you have to use 'cd' command and have to go to your project folder. Then give 'npm start'.